# powershell - how to access shared folders via SFTP

Tags: powershell, sftp, vpn

I have VPN tunnel with 2 computers. When I connect with WinSCP (SFTP client) to second computer, I can see shared folders. The problem is, that I need to copy files from first computer to second with powershell script. Is it possible to access the shared folders via SFTP with Powershell? Thank you..

Comment: http://www.networkworld.com/community/node/23097

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're wanting to use PowerShell to manage the process, use [PSCP.exe](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) from the developer of [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/).  That way you can do command line file transfers and don't have to worry about the GUI tools.

Comment: Thank you, I'm testing winscp now. This will be my second option if it won't work.